# Pair equality on components

Tags: equality, idris

I would like to define a function of the following type

```
pairEquality :
     (a, b : (obj1, obj2))
  -> (fst a) = (fst b)
  -> (snd a) = (snd b)
  -> a = b
```

but I am a bit at loss with the implementation.

I know I can write

```
pairEquality' :
     a1 = b1
  -> a2 = b2
  -> (a1, a2) = (b1, b2)
```

but that doesn't seem to compile where I need to use it (that's another question: what's the big difference between the two functions?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first implementation is pretty straight-forward. Once you split the tuples to get `pairEquality (a, b) (x, y) prf1 prf2 = ?t` and inspect the the hole, you already see, that the compiler infers that `prf1 : a = x`, `prf2: b = y`, alas:

```
pairEquality :
     (a, b : (obj1, obj2))
  -> (fst a) = (fst b)
  -> (snd a) = (snd b)
  -> a = b
pairEquality (x, y) (x, y) Refl Refl = Refl
```

In `pairEquality` you de-construct the tuples and in `pairEquality'` you construct the tuples. Latter is usually a better approach, and I guess you can change something in your caller function so it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I actually find out I can define `pairEquality` in terms of `pairEquality'` as

```
pairEquality :
     (a, b : (obj1, obj2))
  -> (fst a) = (fst b)
  -> (snd a) = (snd b)
  -> a = b
pairEquality (a1, a2) (b1, b2) = pairEquality' {a1} {a2} {b1} {b2}
```